# Modify background color for select in angular

Tags: angular

How do I modify the background of a select in angular? Instead of the grey background list that opens up, I want to change it to white. How do I do that?

Here is my select

```
<select id="areaOfExpertiseFilter" class="form-control"
                required [(ngModel)]="filterBy.areaOfExpertise"
                name="areaOfExpertise" (change)='onAOESelected()'>
          <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected hidden>Area of Expertise</option>
          <option [ngValue]="areaOfExpertise" *ngFor="let areaOfExpertise of filters.areaOfExpertises" >{{areaOfExpertise.displayName}}</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some simple CSS rules.

Here's a screenshot of what you should do in your component's CSS file and the result you'll get:

[image]

The first rule:

```
select.form-control {
    background-color:red;
}
```

will change the color of the input. As the second rule:

```
select.form-control > option{
  background-color:bisque;
}
```

will change the color of the options.